# How to find jsp filename for a UI element on a webpage

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Hi and thanks for the help,

I am trying to add a button on my company's intranet site, but dang if there aren't 1000 jsp files obscuring my effort.

How do I find out which file contains a specific UI element?.

Here is what FireBug shows me:

```
<div class="TabContent TitleTabContainer">
<a class="TabTitle" role="tab" onclick="return !1;"href="javascript:void(null);"         title="Documents" style="width: auto;">Documents</a>
</div>
```

Thank you,
WH

Comment: Just do a search&find in Eclipse?

Comment: All of the website .jsps are stored inside .jar and .war files -- I don't believe Search and Find will work, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Uh, you mentioned that you're using Eclipse, so I understood that you've all the original project source code.